# How to use a value from a Coroutine or tell when it's done

Tags: unity-game-engine

For instance, when calling a web API with the WWW-class, I'd like a value returned or some feedback on when it's done and its status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well then, me, let me show me a neat way of doing this!

Here we make an IEnumerator that takes in an Action (method in our case) as parameter and call it when our WWW is done:

```
    public static IEnumerator GetSomething(Action<string> callback)
    {
        // The www-stuff isn't really important to what I wish to mediate
        WWWForm wwwForm = new WWWForm();
        wwwForm.AddField("select", "something");
        WWW www = new WWW(URL, wwwForm);
        yield return www;

        if (www.error == null)
        {
            callback(www.text);
        }
        else
        {
            callback("Error");
        }
    }
```

And this is how we use it:

```
StartCoroutine(
    GetSomething((text) => 
    {
        if (text != "Error")
        {
            // Do something with the text you got from the WWW
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle the error
        }
    })
);
```

The parameter we send in is `(text)` which is a namelessly declared method. We call it "callback" in the IEnumerator but it can be called anything, what's important is that it calls the method we have declared in the parameters of where we call the method GetSomething.

Comment: If we all start asking questions we already have the answer to, SO becomes useless. Also, this is nothing new, there are plenty of that questions with that answer.

Comment: @Everts You [can](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) ask a question and answer it if you think it will help others. This would have but, unfortunately,  is a duplicate.

Comment: @Programmer Oh wow, and it's near identical. My bad, I didn't find it and wanted a future reference for myself and figured others would benefit from this as well.

Everts perhaps you should add a suggestion for stackoverflow to remove the self-answering feature if you truly believe so.

Comment: That's fine. People will still find it useful