# unity3d - Separate UI Thread for Android

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, unity-game-engine

In my VR app for Android Smartphones (I think it doesn't matter whether it is a VR app or not) I download 6 big images from Street View and built a skybox out of it. During this process the whole app incl. environment and UI freezes. After ~10sec the process is down and Street View is there.

**How can I seperate the main processing from UI? So the phone is working, but should not freeze. This is a common web problem, but how can I solve this in Unity for Android?**

Thank you!

code:

```
private byte[] GetStreetviewTexture(string url) {
WWW www = new WWW(url);

while (!www.isDone) ;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
{
    Debug.LogWarning("Unable to DL texture: " + www.error);
}
else
{
    bytes = www.texture.EncodeToPNG();
}
return bytes;
}
```

Comment: What code are you currently using?

Comment: i put the code into the post  `   private byte[] GetStreetviewTexture(string url) {
    WWW www = new WWW(url);

    while (!www.isDone) ;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Unable to DL texture: " + www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        bytes = www.texture.EncodeToPNG();
    }
    return bytes;
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use an IEnumerator to thread it with a Unity Coroutine. If you're already using this, which I'm assuming you actually are - could it be a performance issue that freezes the device? If so, check the [Unity profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) and/or [Unity Remote](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote4.html). Coroutines are, like comments suggest, not a Thread - but emulates a threaded behaviour.

Basic Coroutine code:

```
void SomeMethod() {
    StartCoroutine(Threaded());
}

IEnumerator Threaded() {
    // Do something
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
}
```

Check out the [WWW class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) and how to make an IEnumerator wait for download to complete

---

Update responding to OP's follow-up question:

[How to tell when a Coroutine is done and get a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41445427/how-to-use-a-value-from-a-coroutine-or-tell-when-its-done/41445428#41445428)

---

Update responding to OPs follow-up follow-up question:
This is a simplified example of your current logic/flow. **NOTE: THIS DOES NOT WORK**. *Do not use this code as an example for how it's supposed to be done, I just want to illustrate the differences in how you should approach your problem.*

```
void ButtonClicked() {
     SetTexture()
}

void SetTexture() {
    Texture texture = GetTexture()
    Object.texture = texture;
}

Texture GetTexture() {
    Texture texture;
    StartCoroutine(DownloadTexture((textureCallback) => {
        texture = textureCallback;
    }));
    return texture;
}

IEnumerator DownloadTexture(Action<Texture> callbackTexture)
{
    WWW www = new WWW(URL);
    yield return www;

    callback(www.texture);
}
```

Not only does this not work, because a Coroutine is run asyncronously with the rest of the code, but it's not a good approach for this task.

Instead of doing

> Button click -> set texture -> start download -> error setting texture -> download finished

you want:

> Button click -> download texture -> wait for it to be done -> set texture

Like this:

```
void ButtonClick() {
    StartCoroutine(DownloadTexture((callbackTexture) => {
        SetTexture(callbackTexture); // Will run SetTexture when Coroutine DownloadTexture is completed.
    }));
}

IEnumerator DownloadTexture(Action<Texture> callbackTexture)
{
    WWW www = new WWW(URL);
    yield return www;

    callback(www.texture);
}

void SetTexture(Texture texture) {
     object.texture = texture;
}
```

Note that this is just flow-code. Your code will look different, using byte[] instead of Texture and I don't know if you're using a Button to start the texture-setting. This can be any sort of trigger/starting point.

Comment: "use an IEnumerator to thread" Coroutine is not a Thread. WWW is running in another Thread and provides a function to yield it but coroutine is not a Thread. "use an IEnumerator to wait for WWW" would have been appropriate but without OP's code, we can't tell what's going on.

Comment: Right, but it simulates a threaded behaviour - which I initially thought OP wanted. I managed to not read the bolded words...

Comment: I think my answer might apply... I don't think it's a threaded performance increase you need, just a slighly enhanced code. Try using a Coroutine instead, like the example in the WWW-class documentation.

Comment: As you can see, I need to return byte[] bytes in this method. Do you have any idea to return something with Coroutine? @Fredrik

Comment: Was my answer; Coroutines, what you were looking for? And sure, here's how I usually use callbacks in Coroutines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41445427/how-to-use-a-value-from-a-coroutine-or-tell-when-its-done/41445428#41445428. Change the `Action<string>` to `Action<byte[]>` and you're good to go!

Comment: Okay, that worked but the freezing is still the same. Now I tried to put only the www download stuff into Corotuin. I outsourced that as "answer" because in comments is not enough space @Fredrik

Comment: See, I updated my code, @Fredrik . The chronology is not correct.

Comment: The chronology is correct because of how your logic is written. Please see my updated answer on how to correct the flow of the program.

Comment: The flow seems to be the following: StartCoroutine(DownloadTexture) -> DownloadTexture -> step out of StartCoroutine(DownloadTexture) -> SetTexture. See console outout of my "answer"

Comment: It should be working from what I can tell now. To help you understand the flow, I opened paint and drew some: http://imgur.com/a/60sIm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136171/discussion-between-fmielke-and-fredrik).

Comment: This image is great, thank you very much. Unfortunately it doesn't work , becaus of the described behaviour. Maybe it is really a problem of my loop which is not visible on code at the moment. I updated my "answer" again