# How to change data in database from Unity 5 c#?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, database, unity-game-engine

i have set up my DB and my application in Unity 5. How i need to be able to change the data in the database from Unity. How can i do that? I am using c# in Unity and php for DB (phpMyAdmin). I'll post my php and c# code with a picture of the DB (early stages).

[Data/information i want to be able to change (Excuse me that it stands on Norwegian)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVXWn.png)

php code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbName = "bh";
    $CheckForBaasnr = "ChkForBaasnr";
    //Make Connection

    $conn = new mysqli ($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
    $conn->set_charset('utf8');
    //Check Connection

    if(!$conn)
    {
        die("Connection Failed.". mysqli_connect_error());
    }



if($_REQUEST['sql'] = "Baasnr")
{
    $NoeAnnet = $_GET['sql'];

    $_REQUEST['sql']= "SELECT ID, Medlemsnr, EierFNavn, EierENavn, EierAdresse, EierPnr, EierPSted, EierTLF, EierRolle, Pirnr, Baasnr, Naustnr, Opplaggsplassnr, Baattype, Baatmerke, Baatmodell, BaatAarsmodell, BaatStr, Strom, BaasPris, PrisMnd, Vakt, DugnadsTimer, EierEpost FROM medlem WHERE Baasnr = ".$NoeAnnet;

    $result = mysqli_query ($conn ,$_REQUEST['sql']);



}




if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

        //show data for each row

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {

            echo "#".$row['ID']. "#".$row['Medlemsnr']."#".$row['EierFNavn']. "#".$row['EierENavn']. "#".$row['EierAdresse']."#".$row['EierPnr']."#".$row['EierPSted']. "#".$row['EierTLF']."#".$row['EierRolle']."#".$row['Pirnr']."#".$row['Baasnr']."#".$row['Naustnr']."#".$row['Opplaggsplassnr']. "#".$row['Baattype']."#".$row['Baatmerke']."#".$row['Baatmodell']."#".$row['BaatAarsmodell']."#".$row['BaatStr']."#".$row['Strom']."#".$row['BaasPris']."#".$row['PrisMnd']."#".$row['Vakt']."#".$row['DugnadsTimer']. "#".$row['EierEpost']."#";
        }


}




?>
```

C# code:
Well here is a problem. I can't figure out how to do this part!

Hope this explanation was clear enough!

Comment: Here is an example: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823854/How-to-connect-SQL-Database-to-your-Csharp-program

Comment: And for mysql: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL

Comment: your code is wide open to **SQL Injection attacks!** use paramerized statements to protect your database.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann yes i know it is at this time, as i said early stages.

Comment: Thanks @Tatranskymedved

Comment: @user7642373 [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484329/save-load-xml-file-on-a-web-server-using-unity-c/42485749#42485749) where I demonstrate a simple workflow of using database with unity.

Comment: @Fredrik Thanks mate! <3

Comment: Was that what you were looking for? Let me know if you need another example or have any questions or such.